In Google Cloud SQL Postgres how do I avoid log_min_messages as not superuser?
There's no way in google cloud sql postgres to make a superuser. So I get:
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 16.3 (Postgres.app)
psql postgres://postgres:password@ip/db
FATAL: permission denied to set parameter "log_min_messages"

when I try and connect. I've set this flag to "info" but still when I connect it tries and change the value and this error is fatal. Without making a superuser how can I get around this?

"Superuser restrictions and privileges
Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL is a managed service, so it restricts access to certain system procedures and tables that require advanced privileges. In Cloud SQL, customers cannot create or have access to users with superuser attributes."

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users

This is a client problem more than a server problem.  As far as I know, this is only FATAL if you try to set it via PGOPTIONS on the client. So  change your client configuration not to do that.  Or tell us what the client is and how it is configured.

psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 16.3 (Postgres.app)

Why is that client trying to change log_min_statements?  That it is not the default behavior.  Do you have PGOPTIONS environment variable set?  Is it something in the connection string?  Is it something in the .psqlrc file (although in that case it doesn't seem to be FATAL, in my testing)?

no, no PGOPTIONS env var. To test that maybe my 16.3 (Postgres.app) was the problem, I did brew install postgresql@15 and tried to connect with that v15 psql binary. But I didn't get the path right and after installing it I ran the original 16.3 again and... drum roll, the very act of that brew install somehow fixed the problem!

I did
brew install postgresql@15

and that somehow fixed it for me. Even though I'm still using my original psql (PostgreSQL) 16.3 (Postgres.app). I can now login without that FATAL error but no idea why this fixed it.

These are called "database flags". You can change the settings by using your Google Cloud Console
After a change you have to restart the instance to activate the new flag.

i did this. Still get the error. psql: error: connection to server, port 5432 failed: FATAL:  permission denied to set parameter "log_min_messages"

In that case you have to contact GCP because they claim that this should work.

No matter what the server-wide default it, his client is still trying to change this setting locally and is not allowed to do that. This needs to be fixed on the client side.
